# Sorting GroupBy nested Lists Lambda

Tags: c#-4.0

I have data of a listeners choice of music over 8 years, I've been tasked with finding the most listened artist in a given year. The artists name must be returned to string. I was requested to do this using a single lambda statement, and I'm lost.

Here's what I have so far. 
(where time is the system DateTime of the original listening)

```
string mostPopular = musicDataList.Where(x => x.Time.Year.ToString() == year).GroupBy(y => y.Artist).OrderByDescending;
```

I put the semi-colon there because I don't know what comes next.

I know that:
I need to limit the search by year first,
I group the result by artist, so that I can order the results by how many objects are in the list,

What I  don't know:
Syntax for sorting the nested lists following the GroupBy by how many objects found within,
How to OrderBy number of objects in each element of the list, 
Then extracting the artist string property from the object.

Yes this is for a class, that's why it has to be so specific with the single lambda statement, I'm just not to the understanding of manipulating nested lists to where I can arrive at the correct syntax on my own.

If anyone has any reading on how to arrive at the solution, I'd be grateful, I just can't seem to find the right information.

```
string mostPopular = musicDataList.Where(x => x.Time.Year.ToString() == year).GroupBy(y => y.Artist).OrderByDescending(z => z.Count()).First().Select(b => b.Artist).ToString();
```

This is my thinking. Pare this list down to only the year being reviewed. Group the objects by artist, order the group list by the .count of nested lists, take the first element, select the artist property, and push to string.

That doesn't work however. I'm not sure what's going wrong here, and nothing I'm reading online is helping me figure out how to sort the inner list of objects by how MANY objects there are in the inner lists.

Comment: After your group by you're going to have an artist name as a key that points to a collection of records. Order by the length of that collection. Im on my phone but pseudo code would be musicDataList.Where(x => x.Time.Year.ToString() == year).GroupBy(y => y.Artist).OrderByDescending(x => x.Group.Count()). Group will be a collection of whatever makes up musicDataList. I'm not sure what the exact property is called to get your Grouping.

Comment: I don't know that there is one. My list is constructed straight from a loop that strips a text file of info. The list is an object of the "Play" class, with title, artist, time, and album as properties. 
It strips the data from the text file in that order.

So what I have is a list that contains that line of data, then I'm cramming several lines in list form into a new list. So I'm not sure what Group name would be

And once that's done, I have to get the artist name from that nested list.  Anyone have a deep dive on how manipulating nested lists works?

Answer (score 0):

```
string difficult = musicDataList.Where(x => x.Time.Year.ToString() == year).GroupBy(y => y.Artist).OrderByDescending(z => z.Count()).First().First().Artist;
```

This wound up working. Selecting the first element of the first (.First().First()) element worked after sorting by .count.

Does anyone know if there is a more efficient way of wording this?

Also any good reading on nested lists, and how to access properties of specific objects nested within a list would be great.